# can user set private/public key values in jarsigner tool java code

Tags: java

i am new to java crytography. i want to sign the zip file before sending it over internet.
to sign the zip file i want to use single secret key for sign and verify the zip. i tried using the jarsigner but it requires public and private key and it random number hence, my question is
can i set the single key as private and public to sign the zip file. i dont want to use the private/public key for sign and verify zip file.
or do we have any mechanism to sign the zip with single secret key in java 11.

Comment: How did you create the “secret key”? Cryptographic signatures fundamentally require a public and private key, no way around this: the whole concept relies on this.

Comment: Private and public keys are components of the same keypair. You cannot use one without the other: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography